# Flutter WebView: Cookies don't seem to persist on old iPhones

Tags: ios, flutter, cookies, webview

I am using [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) package and the persistance of the cookies is not working on physical device iPhone 6, but on iPhone XR works.

iPhone XR uses iOS 15.
iPhone 6 uses iOS 12.

The cookie insertion is in the onPageFinished

```
await webViewController
        ?.runJavascript('document.cookie="ADST=$token;"');
```

After that in order to check I'm getting the cookies like this and the ADST is there:

```
cookies = await webViewController!
      .runJavascriptReturningResult('document.cookie');
```

but after the function ends and the webview loads the url the cookie is not there anymore.